# making one dict with three lists

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have 3 list as below,

```
list1 = [id, name]
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list3 = [a,b,c,d,e]
```

I am trying to make them like this;

```
result = [{id: 1, name: a},{id: 2, name: b},{id: 3, name: c},{id: 4, name: d},{id: 5, name: e}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
[{k: v for k, v in zip(list1, vals)} for vals in zip(list2, list3)]
```